# Need opinions/hints on a design

Tags: uml

I would really like to have your opinion, or any hints to the following design problem, as I am a bit puzzled.

I have two objects, Client and Server, where the Client can refer to many Server objects. Each Server object provides a single method, which the Client can invoke.

What I'd like to do, is change this relation, so that the Client can refer to more Server types, for instance, Server_1 and Server_2. I am currently thinking of using polymorphism, either with Interfaces or Abstract classes. For example, Server_1 and Server_2 extend/implement the Server and the client still keeps a Server reference list. Does that make any sense or there is a better/different way to do it?

Furthemore, I would like to be able to create a chain of calls to the Servers (1 and 2) and store it. Any ideas of how I should go about it? Also, in what way would you implement that in Java? (no code, just ideas).

Comment: what do you mean that the client can "refer" to servers.  Is the client storing variables pointing to server objects?

Comment: @jollarvia, it means that the client can be associated with many servers or [Client]------*[Server]. As a result, the Client will have a data structure which will point to Server objects.

Answer (score 0):

> so that the Client can refer to more Server types,

Inheritance ( Classes Inheritance or Interface Inheritance ) are the way to go.

Also Know As "Specialization".

Your first scenario was similar to:

```
........................................................................
..+--------------------------+..............+------------------------+..
..|         <<class>>        |..............|        <<class>>       |..
..|       CustomerClass      |..............|       ServerClass      |..
..+--------------------------+....uses......+------------------------+..
..| [+] Servers: ServerClass +-----------< >+ [+] void DoSomething() |..
..+--------------------------+..............+------------------------+..
........................................................................
```

Note: "< >" represents a unfilled diamond.

Then:

```
..............................................................................
..+------------------------------+.........+-------------------------------+..
..|         <<abstract>>         |.........|          <<concrete>>         |..
..|         ServerClass          |.........|        PDFPrinterClass        |..
..+------------------------------+.../|....+-------------------------------+..
..| [+] void Print() <<virtual>> |--< |-+--+ [+] void Print() <<override>> |..
..+------------------------------+...\|.|..+-------------------------------+..
........................................|.....................................
........................................|..+-------------------------------+..
........................................|..|         <<concrete>>          |..
........................................|..|       WordPrinterClass        |..
........................................|..+-------------------------------+..
........................................+--+ [+] void Print() <<override>> |..
...........................................+-------------------------------+..
..............................................................................
```

I like to separate Aggregation Associations from Inheritance Associations, as different diagrams.

But, in case, if you still need both:

```
....................................
..+------------------------------+..
..|           <<class>>          |..
..|         CustomerClass        |..
..+------------------------------+..
..| [+] Servers:     ServerClass |..
..+--------------+---------------+..
.................|..................
.................|..................
.................|..................
................< >...........................................................
..+--------------+---------------+.........+-------------------------------+..
..|         <<abstract>>         |.........|          <<concrete>>         |..
..|         ServerClass          |.........|        PDFPrinterClass        |..
..+------------------------------+.../|....+-------------------------------+..
..| [+] void Print() <<virtual>> |--< |-+--+ [+] void Print() <<override>> |..
..+------------------------------+...\|.|..+-------------------------------+..
........................................|.....................................
........................................|..+-------------------------------+..
........................................|..|         <<concrete>>          |..
........................................|..|       WordPrinterClass        |..
........................................|..+-------------------------------+..
........................................+--+ [+] void Print() <<override>> |..
...........................................+-------------------------------+..
..............................................................................
```

> create a chain of calls to the Servers (1 and 2) and store it.

You may like to investigate about the "Command" Software Design Pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it confirms what I was thinking of doing. It's an acceptable answer for the first part of my question. Any ideas on the second one (especially on storing chains of calls)?